# prove that $\Sigma \vdash \phi_1$ and $\Sigma \vdash \phi_2$ leads to $\Sigma \vdash \phi_1 \wedge \phi_2$.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I try to prove that if $\Sigma \vdash \phi_1$ and $\Sigma \vdash \phi_2$ then $\Sigma \vdash \phi_1 \wedge \phi_2$.

Notice that, the ONLY rule of inference of the system is modes ponens and the set of logical axioms are all the tautologies.

I know that I can use completness theorem of propositional calculus to prove that easily but the point is , I was trying to prove completness theorem of propositional logic and to finish the proof I need to prove this as a claim which is I'm stuck with.

I know that I need to prove that $\Sigma \vdash \neg(\phi_1\rightarrow \neg\phi_2)$.

Any ideas or hints?

Comment: Question as you formulated it can not be proven inside system because there is no $\vdash$ inside system. $\vdash$ is part of metalanguage.

Comment: @Trismegistos, If you mean that $\vdash$ is a meta symbol, of course this is true. I didn't mean that it's part of the system - language. Could you clarify more what you mean, please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\phi_1 \rightarrow (\phi_2 \rightarrow (\phi_1 \land \phi_2))$ is a *tautology*. Thus, apply *modus ponens* twice ...

Comment: This is the tautology I was looking for all the day :D